# How do I access the title attribute with xpath?

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, nodes, html-agility-pack

So I am trying to access the `title` attribute in the colors section.
So if you were to hover over any of the small images to the right side of the product you will see that it says the `Color` name.
I've managed to navigate to there but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the `title` attribute. Currently it's printing out nodes but I want to access the title attribute.

How do i properly access the title attribute and print out the corresponding color to the pictures?

[This is the test link I am using (AliExpress)](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/LIGE-Fashion-Men-Watch-Brand-Quartz-Men-WristWatch-Wrist-Full-Steel-Chronograph-Waterproof-Male-Clock-2018/32864666693.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.300.1a89c539R2uuk8&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10151_5711320_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_10340_10341_10696_10084_5722520_10083_10618_10307_10301_10303_5711220_10059_5722620_5722920_308_5722720_5722820_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620_10814_10815-5711320,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_7&algo_expid=dcb0f58b-cec8-408e-a753-9468c2ad1a84-37&algo_pvid=dcb0f58b-cec8-408e-a753-9468c2ad1a84&priceBeautifyAB=0)

```
Console.WriteLine("Product URL: ");
            //Declare the URL
            string url = Console.ReadLine();
            // HtmlWeb - A Utility class to get HTML document from http
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            //Load() Method download the specified HTML document from an Internet resource.
            var doc = web.Load(url);

            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class = 'item-sku-image']");
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                //var colors = node.Attributes["/a[title]"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(node);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and iterate over the following X-Path: `//li[@class = 'item-sku-image']/a/img/@title`, or else, replace this: `//li[@class = 'item-sku-image']`, with this: `//li[@class = 'item-sku-image']/a/img`, and then check the attributes of the nodes.

It should yield a series of strings which contain the title you are after.

Comment: I shall try that! Also, when learning xpath is there a set of rules you should follow when traversing through the nodes?

Comment: I haven't used X-Path that much to be honest. What I Would recommend is to stick to Id's, if possible instead of CSS classes, and try to keep things simple.

Comment: @npinto How do I extract the title content from the node? InnerText returns an emptys tring